# SpringBoot Kafka: Bean method 'kafkaTemplate' in 'KafkaAutoConfiguration' is not loaded

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using springboot and trying to write a KafkaProducer to push messages in Kafka queue.
I have created these methods in @Configuration class.

```
@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate(){
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
}

@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress); //bootstrapAddress holds address of kafka server
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
}
```

And I have Autowired this KafkaTemplate bean in my KafkaMessageProducer class that takes care of the handling of send function of KafkaTemplate.

```
@Autowired
KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;
```

But I am facing this error when I try to compile my code

```
Field kafkaTemplate in <pathoffile>.KafkaMessageProducer required a bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate' that could not be found.
    - Bean method 'kafkaTemplate' in 'KafkaAutoConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'avroKafkaTemplate'
Action:Consider revisiting the conditions above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate' in your configuration.
```

Also, if I try to exclude KafkaAutoConfiguration in my Spring project, I get error like "Bean cannot be loaded as KafkaAutoConfiguration is disabled'.
Any idea why I am getting this Bean error and what may be the solution?

EDIT:- I found following bean in a jar file used by my project

```
@Bean
@Conditional({EnableQueueCondition.class})
public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
    KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate(this.producerFactory());
    kafkaTemplate.setProducerListener(new ProducerListenerImpl());
    return kafkaTemplate;
}
```

So, this is where the error is coming from, but I don't how to tell spring to not look to this bean, and use the bean I defined. I have tried using Primary and Qualifier annotations on the bean, it still gives the same error. Is there might be a possibility that my defined bean is not created or not found, and KafkaAutoConfiguration is then looking for the default bean that is override by avroKafkaTemplate bean? What may be the solution of this problem?

Answer (score 2):

By default spring boot provide KafkaTemplate bean if you add kafka dependency in POM.

You just need to define the properties in your application.yml file
example:

```
server: port: 9000
spring:
   kafka:
     consumer:
        bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
        group-id: group_id
        auto-offset-reset: earliest
        key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
        value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
     producer:
        bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
        key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
        value-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```

enable auto configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
```

and autowire the kafkaTemplate:

```
 @Autowired
 private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;
```

If your case the auto config factory is looking for `ProducerFactory<String, Strng>`which does not match with your configuration.

```
 @Bean
 @ConditionalOnMissingBean(ProducerFactory.class)
        public ProducerFactory<String, Strng> kafkaProducerFactory()
```

so rename your producerFactory() to kafkaProducerFactory(), it will solve your issue.

Comment: Imran, renaming producerFactory() to kafkaProducerFactory() didn't work, it still shows the same error. Dependency is added in POM file.

Comment: In my code it’s working.... I just defined my bean like this:            @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate kafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, String> pf) {
        return new KafkaTemplate(pf); }                                                  Also make sure to use  EnableAutoConfiguration

Comment: Yes it is enabled, I updated the question with some additional details, please have a look and see if it might help in arriving at a solution.

Comment: If that bean is not required in your project then you can exclude specific classes from being scanned into beans with the excludeFilters parameter of the @ComponentScan annotation.
Ex:  @ComponentScan(value = {'com.xyz.abc'}, excludeFilters = {
  @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = { firstClass.class, secondClass.class })
})

Answer (score 1):

From the stacktrace, there is another `KafkaTemplate` bean - `avroKafkaTemplate`. So I guess there is another configuration, duplicating `KafkaTemplate` definition.

Comment: yes maybe but I am not sure. What do you think how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have any configuration with `avroKafkaTemplate()` method ? This is definetely a custom defined bean.

Comment: Codebase on which I am working is pretty large, but even on searching through it I dont find any matches with avroKafkaTemplate

Comment: Do you have any dependencies providing their own configuration ? Like other submodule, which also has a configuration bean ?

Comment: Yes, there are loads of them.

Comment: So, probably one of them defines `avroKafkaTemplate` bean

Comment: Could you try to add `@Primary` qualifier to your `KafkaTemplate` bean definition please?

Comment: Yes I tried it and also @Qualifier, but still same error. Also, I found a Bean with avroKafkaTemplate in a jar file my project is using, so that is where spring is getting this bean. But I think, avroKafkaTemplate is looked up only when KafkaTemplate bean(that is defined by me) is not found, and default bean is not returned because of this avroKafka bean. What do you think we may do in this scenario?

Comment: Is your `@Configuration` class defined properly and got loaded? could you please confirm that your `KafkaTemplate` bean definition is actually loaded? For example, print to console inside method.